# What is the noun for knowledgeable?

Tags: word-request

What is the noun for knowledgeable? knowledgeableness looks awkward. Thanks!

Comment: Probably not what you are after, but "literate" can be used as noun, e.g.: "But for the illiterates and even many literates, who throng the Collectorate seeking assistance, their services are indispensable".

Comment: @Nico *Literate* refers only to knowledge of written language, unlike *knowledgeability*, which refers to knowledge of whatever matter is at hand.

Comment: Apparently, knowledgeableness is in the [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knowledgeable)

Comment: Tim, do you need the name for the person or for the property of being knowledgeable?

Comment: @Nico *Knowlegeableness* had a modest currency down to about 1950 but has since been supersededed by *knowledgeability*.

Comment: By knowledgeable, I mean a little more than normal people, so that he can pass wisdom to others if he is willing to and know how to. I don't have the name of a specific person. It is just a general expectation.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is very common, but in general you'll be better off choosing "knowledgeability" over "knowledgeableness".

[image: knowledgeableness vs. knowledgeability]
<sup>Source: [Google Ngram Viewer, "knowledgeability, knowledgeableness"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2Cknowledgeability%2Cknowledgeableness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknowledgeability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknowledgeableness%3B%2Cc0)</sup>

You could also simply refer to someone's knowledge. For instance, given the following choice:

1. Pat has the knowledge to be helpful to new recruits.
2. Pat has the knowledgeability to be helpful to new recruits.

I'd choose #1 every time. It's hard to imagine a scenario where it wouldn't be clearer to just say "knowledge". This makes sense, because that's where "knowledgeable" came from in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'learned' or 'educated', e.g. 'he was a very learned man'. (Note that there are two syllables in learned, which are both stressed, unlike when it is used as a verb).

Comment: But one may be *knowledgeable* about many subjects--plumbing, for instance, or heavy metal--without deep learning or formal education.

Comment: This is true, thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps it would be best instead to use the term 'expert on X' or 'expertise of X' instead, depending on what the context is.

Comment: These are adjectives. Tim has asked for a noun.

Comment: Yes indeed Tyler, apologies, my mistake.